# Uninstalling Blender previous versions

Tags: installation

I would like to uninstall many of the previous versions of Blender to free up some space.
When I go to the control panel to uninstall I cannot distinguish between the versions.

Can I simply go to C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation and delete the previous versions or is there a way to distinguish from the previous versions in the control panel? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can delete it from Program Files. Or just click on the blender icon in your control panel and it should show the version at the bottom.